# How to host a SwiftUI App on your own server?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, apple-developer, b2b

I would like to sell a macOS application written in swiftUI.
Apple provides several options to distribute the app, but when I understood it correctly all of these options require that you use in some way their hosting service.
My application is not for the public, and specialised for one task/company.
Is there a way to host and distribute the App all by yourself by having a download link on your website, just like the most third party apps (DaVinci Resolve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a “Developer Signed” app.

https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/

Notarise the archive in Xcode organiser where you see all the archives listed. This is automatic and is not a review process.